# Ensure that child model never exists without a parent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent model called `Page`, which has a one-to-many relationship with my other model `HotTip`.

I only ever add a new `HotTip` to a given `Page`, and I never want a `HotTip` to exist without a parent `Page`.

I can create a new `Page` by POSTing to the `Page` model, but if I POST to the `HotTip` model it creates a new `HotTip` with no parent `Page`.

How do I assign one object as a child of another on creation?

Comment: Show us some code that you've tried so far

Comment: It seems your HotTip database's page_id is nullable. And if you don't select any page_id while creating a new HotTip where will it come from in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass page_id when creating HotTip. Should look like this:

```
$hotTip = new HotTip;
$hotTip->name = $request->name;
$hotTip->another_field = $request->another_field;
$hotTip->page_id = $request->page_id;
$hotTip->save();
```

Comment: I ended up doing this. I put a hidden input field in the form with `name=page_id`, which, when posted to the controller, automatically updated the model with the correct parent page id. Just had to make sure to add that column in my database migration. Thanks!